# How do I sort the orders starting by the latest date at the top using *ngfor in Angular: 9.0.1

Tags: angular, sorting, ngfor

Here is my current code

```
<tbody>
      <tr style="color: #09052e" *ngFor="let order of orders" routerLink="/orders/{{ order.id }}">
        <th># {{ order.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ order.orderDate | date: "medium" }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.buyerEmail }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.total | currency: "R" }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.status }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**currently its sorting with the latest date at the bottom of the page**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzngM.png)

Comment: You could use a filter, but I would would manipulate the original array in the .ts file to ensure the array is in the order you want and then the display is a a straight iteration. It will not really mean much for small lists - but it will be more performant for larger or more comlicated arrays

Comment: I fixed the it using  using *ngFor="let order of orders.slice().reverse()", I now have the desired result.

Comment: yes - but as I indicated in my coment - that is not a very performant approach - when interacting with data it is ALWAYS preferable to separate code / data manipulation from the rendering and display.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using this type of html with Angular (and not with something like a sortable mat-table), then what @gavgrif is saying is correct - you want to do the sort in the .ts once. If you have this logic on the html side of things, you may be running the piece of code way more often than you think.

To see what we mean, you could instead refer to a function: let order of ordersByDateDesc(), where ordersByDateDesc() returns orders.slice().reverse(), but before the return statement, have a console.log('how often is this called?').

In your console log you may see that the function (and thus the slicing and reverse sorting) is actually run A LOT. This at least has been my experience in the past.